# Java generic list return type

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I'm having some problems with a method returning a generic list. The code is basically this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private List<MyListElement> myList = new ArrayList<MyListElement>();

    public <E> List<E> getGenericList(){
        return new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public void thisWorks(){
        List<MyListElement> newList = getGenericList();
        myList.addAll(newList);
    }

    public void thisDoesntWork(){
        myList.addAll(getGenericList());
    }

    public void thisDoesntWorkEither(){
        for(MyListElement elem : getGenericList()){
            fiddle();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the `thisDoesntWork()` method not work, and is there any other way around it (other than doing it the `thisWorks()` way which isn't always practical)?

Comment: When it is not practical it means you should not be doing it. Even your `thisWorks` method is unsafe, because you are assuming your `genericList` will hold `String` (which you cannot tell for sure from your code).

Comment: getGenericList() returns a List<E>, but you need to call addAll() with a List<String>.   List<E> is not the same as List<String>, hence the error.  So why is myList declared to be List<String> rather than List<E>?

Comment: @SJuan76: There's no way around it. The original data source contains objects, but we need to be able to treat the contents as strings. This could in theory lead to ClassCastExceptions yes, but hopefully we will be able to keep track of what kind of list is contained.

Comment: The pass from `Object` to `String` is typically done using `toString()`. Just saying

Comment: That's a good point, but String was just an example. I need to be able to handle other types too. In any case, if the elements are not actually Strings, adding the results of toString() to the lists will likely lead to even more confusion than a ClassCastException would. I edited the question to reflect that it's not actually String related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer what type to choose for the type parameter `<E>` of the generic method `getGenericList()` in `thisDoesntWork()`.

In this case you need to explicitly state the Type for the type argument by calling `<MyListElement>getGenericList()`

Alternatively you can change the signature of `getGenericList()` to accept a `Class<E>` argument. Then you would invoke `getGenericList(MyListElement.class)` in both `thisWorks()` and `thisDoesntWork()`. Admittedly that's a bit more verbose, but definitly more intuitive to clients of your method.

I would say as a general rule, try to make the type arguments of your generic methods be inferrable from that method's arguments.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have both a getGenericList() AND a getGenericList(Class<E>) version? That would let the caller pick which one he wants to use.

Comment: Can you please explain me how can we add a list of strings to mylist, which its of a different type?

Comment: Thanks for poitning that out, my answer still reflected the question's original type, which was String. I've edited my answer to match the current form of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can change `thisDoesntWork()` like so:

```
  public void thisDoesntWork(){ // well, it works now
      myList.addAll(this.<String>getGenericList());
  }
```

You need to tell the compiler what type `getGenericList()` is dealing with.

Comment: What happens when Generic list doesn't hold a String?

Comment: Since `myList` is expecting a `String`, we know we're dealing with `String`s. If it were some other type, the code would have to change accordingly.

Comment: _getGenericList_ returns a new empty List of the specified type... so how could it contain anything?

Comment: getGenericList() is just an example method to simplify the code as much as possible. In the real application it will return a real list and in theory the objects inside could be some other type. I would assume the result is a ClassCastException.

Comment: In your revised example, you _still_ know the type of `myList` (now it is `MyListElement`), so you can replace `String` with `MyListElement` in my example. I'm guessing your actual situation is different than what your example is showing.

Comment: @jahroy: it doesn't contain anything, but that's irrelevant. We are trying to tell the compiler what type to infer for `E`

Comment: @jahroy: We are not talking about the runtime (at runtime there is no difference between lists of different types). We are talking about the compile time. At compile-time, each expression has a definite type, that is inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The type argument to the generic method `<E> getGenericsList()` can be passed at call time:

```
this.<String>getGenericsList()
```

otherwise the compiler does its best to deduce it from the context. When you assign the returned object to a `List<String>` reference, the compiler hence infers that you passed `String` as the type *argument*.

Given the [List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
List<E> {
  void addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
}
```

the compiler doesn't seem to be able to infer the correct type, and to be honest I don't know if this is because it is not smart enough, or because it doesn't want to carry the *responsibility* by design.

I even made a test to see if the problem is the wildcard, or if `addAll()` cannot infer the type arguments from the parameterized type, but nothing seems to work:

```java
public class GenericsList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // same signature as Java API
        List<String> base = new List<String>();
        base.addAll(GenericsList.getList()); // ERROR!

        // addAll() doesn't use a wildcard
        List2<String> base2 = new List2<String>();
        base2.addAll(getList2()); // ERROR!

        // what about a generic method?
        addAll(base, getList()); // ERROR!
    }

    static <E> List<E> getList() {
        return new List<E>();
    }

    static <E> void addAll(List<E> src, List<E> other) {}

    static <E> List2<E> getList2() {
        return new List2<E>();
    }

    static class List<E> {
        void addAll(List<? extends E> other) {}
    }

    static class List2<E> {
        void addAll(List2<E> other) {}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you. 
`getGenericList()` should know what it is returning and that should be compatible with your list type.

**You need not cast it to String or any other as suggested by others as it will restrict your getGenericList method intention by tying it to string type.**

```
public class MyClass{
    private List<MyListElement> myList = new ArrayList<MyListElement>();

    public <E extends MyListElement> List<E> getGenericList(){
        return new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public void thisWorks(){
        List<MyListElement> newList = getGenericList();
        myList.addAll(newList);
    }

    public void thisDoesntWork(){
        myList.addAll(getGenericList());
    }

    public void thisDoesntWorkEither(){
        for(MyListElement elem : getGenericList()){
            fiddle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly there is no need to cast the list to anything

Comment: If MyListElement or its subclasses would be the only elements that could be in the list, there wouldn't be a problem. Your solution falls apart when the getGenericList needs to be able to return other type of lists.

Comment: List<MyListElement> newList = getGenericList();

I don't understand this. If getGenericList() should return other type of lists then it can't be assigned to newList which is of type List<MyListElement>.

And also in the answer that you have accepted, the solution is asking you to send class type to getGenericList method.